# An entity belongs to another entity. Should a REST API provide just the ID of its parent, or its endpoint?

Tags: rest, api-design

Say a `dictionary` belongs to a `language`. For the endpoint `dictionary/{id}`, which is preferable out of:

`{..., 'language_id': {id}, ...}`

and:

`{..., 'language': '/language/{id}', ...}`

?

Comment: Your second example looks close to HATEOAS, you can represent those links using e.g. HAL http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html.

Answer (score 1):

> Should a REST API provide just the ID of its parent, or its endpoint?

Why not both?

For example, see: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/396152?order=desc&sort=activity&site=softwareengineering  The json representation of this question includes both its identifier and also a "link" that can be used to reach a potentially useful endpoint

Roy Fielding wrote a comment on his own blog, that I think cuts toward the key idea of REST.

> REST doesn’t eliminate the need for a clue. What REST does is concentrate that need for prior knowledge into readily standardizable forms.

Passing along an representation identifier like `en` is *fine*, when that's the information you are trying to trying to communicate.  Any application that understands ISO 639-1 will understand what that sequence of bytes means.

But -- you should be suspicious if you are expecting clients to know to take that value and embed it into another identifier.  If there is "an endpoint" that consumers of this message are going to want to know about, then you should be providing the identifier for that endpoint, rather than expecting the client to assemble it.

The point here being that the server, not the client, chooses which endpoint is appropriate.

URI are *identifiers*, first and foremost.  The notion of a identifier that can also be used as the target of a request is normal.  For example, in the Web Linking standard, extension relation types are [required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2) to be URI.  The identifier is an opaque token at the point of use, but also identifies a resource that describes the semantics of the link relation.